# Express subpath GET returns 404 with no content

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes, mocha.js

I'm dealing with an Express + MongoDB (w/Mongoose) project for an interview for which I need to add an endpoint.

The endpoint is a **GET /listings/ranking** where I'm supposed to get all the products listed and sort them in a descending order by the quantity sold. I wrote the endpoint in the `server/api/listing/index.js` file (only that endpoint, the other was already there):

```
var controller = require("./listing.controller");
var config = include("config/environment");
var router = express.Router();

var { route } = require("endpoint-handler")(router)

route.get("/", controller.getAll);

route.get("/:listing_id", controller.getOne);

route.get("/ranking", controller.getMostSold);

module.exports = router;
```

The code for `getMostSold` in the controller (`server/api/listing/listing.controller`):

```
var Listing = require("./listing.model");

exports.getAll = (req, res) => Listing.find({});

exports.getOne = (req, res) => Listing.findOne({
    listing_id: req.params.listing_id
  })
  .then(listing => {
    if (!listing) {
      throw { name: "NotFound", statusCode: 404 };
    }
    return listing;
  });

exports.getMostSold = (req, res) => {
  var defaultLimit = 3;
  Listing.find({})
    .sort('-quantity')
    .limit(req.query.limit || defaultLimit);
};
```

And the corresponding spec in `server/api/listing/router.spec.js`:

```
var should = require("chai").should();
var request = require('supertest');
var app = include('app').app;
var Listing = require('./listing.model');

describe('Listing', () => {
  var samsung = {...};

  beforeEach((done) => {
    return Listing.create(samsung, done);
  });

  describe('GET /listings', function() {
    it('should return all the listings', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/listings').expect(200, [samsung], done);
    });
  });

  describe('GET /listings/:listing_id', function() {

    it('should return the requested listing', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/listings/MLA1111').expect(200, samsung, done);
    });

    it('should return 404 Not Found when the requested listing does not exist', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/listings/WRONGID').expect(404, done);
    });

  });

  describe('GET /listings/ranking', function() {
    var motoG = {...};
    var onePlus = {...};
    var iPhone = {...};
    Listing.create(motoG);
    Listing.create(onePlus);
    Listing.create(iPhone);

    it('should return the top 3 most sold listings since monitoring started', (done) => {
      request(app).get('/listings/ranking').expect(200, [samsung, motoG, onePlus, iPhone], done);
    });

    it('should return the top N most sold listings since monitoring started', (done) => {
      var topN = 2;
      request(app).get(`/listings/ranking?limit=${topN}`).expect(200, [motoG, samsung], done);
    });
  });
```

Both specs for my endpoint are failing while the other works just fine. And it's not that they're returning something else, they're just **not returning anything at all other than an empty 404**. I tried changed my endpoint's controller's code to be just `Listing.find({})` like for the `.getAll` method, but it's still returning `{}`.

I suspect it's just a routing problem because of what I just said. Even though I changed the code, it's like it's not recognizing that there's an endpoint called `/listings/ranking`.

Here's the `server/routes.js` file just in case:

```
var errors = require("./components/errors");

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use("/listings", require("./api/listing"));
  app.route("/:url(api|components|app|bower_components|assets)/*").get(errors[404]);
};
```

And here's what the project structure looks like:
[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:**
First of all, the way I posted the question was without all of the code in all of the files because I thought it would clutter the post with endpoints and tests that weren't affecting mine. Now the question has another endpoint which is what was causing trouble: **GET /listings/:listing_id**.

Apparently in Express the order of the endpoint definition matters so what happened was that my test was trying to interpret **GET /listings/ranking** as if **ranking** was a **listing_id** only because the **/:listing_id** was defined before it. So it was returning 404 because no listing with the ID "ranking" existed.